# VBA Excel 2010 - Assign chart to a object/variable

Tags: vba, excel

As we all know,

```
Dim wkSheet as Worksheet
Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
```

will make it so the active sheet is defined by `wkSheet` and you can do what you want with it using `wkSheet`

My question is, how do you do this with a chart?

You can use `ActiveChart.` to do almost anything you want with the chart.

However I seem unable to set the chart as a varible/object/shape (or what ever it needs to be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Public Sub cht()

Dim v As Chart

Set v = ActiveChart

End Sub
```

This worked for me.  Is there an active chart?

Comment: The trick after what you've done is to set the Chart.Chartobject, which is where you get to the Series, etc.

Comment: @DougGlancy Other way round actually. `Series` etc belong to `Chart`, which may be contained in a `Chartobject`, unless it's a separate sheet.

Comment: @Rory, Woops. Right you are. Thanks.

Comment: Well I was sure I had tried that ... Seems not ... still thanks for giving me the right answer

Answer (score 1):

If you needed to use the chartObject variable type you can do it this way

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chrt As ChartObject

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set chrt = ws.ChartObjects(wb.ActiveChart.Parent.Name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dim strTemp As String

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(317, xlRadar).Select

strTemp = ActiveChart.Name

Debug.Print strTemp

End Sub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).